# Nested fields in Entity Framework Core: can I fetch everything in one query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to efficiently manipulate complex records with multiple levels of nested fields in C# / ASP.NET Core / Entity Framework Core.

I created a small test app with EF models "Departments > Courses > CourseAuditors".

Here's my query:

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Departments = ctx.Departments.ToList();
        foreach (var department in Departments)
        {
            department.Courses = ctx.Courses
                .Where(c => c.DepartmentID == department.ID)
                .ToList();
            foreach (var course in department.Courses)
            {
                course.CourseAuditors = ctx.CourseAuditors
                    .Where(c => c.CourseID == course.ID)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Q: Is there any way I can get rid of the loops, and read everything in one query?

Here are the models:

**Department.cs**

```
public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentHead { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

**Course.cs**

```
public class Course
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instructor { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CourseAuditor> CourseAuditors { get; set; }
}
```

**CourseAuditor.cs**

```
public class CourseAuditor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
}
```

Our current platform is

- TargetFramework=.net5.0;
- EntityFrameworkCore=5.0.6 (we'd like to migrate to .NET 6.x soon).

My primary concern is SQL-level efficiency (the fewer SQL-level queries/round trips the better!).

Any advice/suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: Does [`ctx.Departments.Include(d => d.Courses).ThenInclude(c => c.CourseAuditors)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?view=efcore-6.0) work? Check out [Eager Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should extend your models with proper relations:

```
public class CourseAuditor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; } // this property is missing
}
```

```
public class Course
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instructor { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; } // this property is missing
    public virtual ICollection<CourseAuditor> CourseAuditors { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your DbContext method `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` you should create relations like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
        .HasMany(c => c.CourseAuditors)
        .WithOne(ca => ca.Course)
        .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.CourseID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
        .HasMany(d => d.Courses)
        .WithOne(c => c.Department)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID);
}
```

After this setup you can now use SQL Join feature - `.Include(...)` in Entity Framework.

Changed method `OnGet()`:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    Departments = ctx.Departments
        .Include(d => d.Courses)
        .ThenInclude(c => c.CourseAuditors)
        .ToList();
}
```

Lastly I would suggest changing naming of properties.

DepartmentID -> DepartmentId 
ID -> Id 
etc.

There's the convention in C# to not capitalize full texts.

Comment: Beautiful - thank you!  I'll let you know if it works.!

Comment: please mark in as an answer if it helps @paulsm4

Comment: I just finished verifying - everything works like a charm! I modified my LINQ, the models, and added your ModelBuilder.  FYI, the test case went from 50++ SQL statements down to exactly one.  Thank you again

Comment: happy to hear because I was writing code from memory and could’ve made some small mistake or typo :P