# Map inherited many-to-many base class to database in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following base class:

```
public class Clearance
{
    public string Pre_Authorization_Number { get; private set; }
    public string Case_Reference_Number { get; private set; }
    public string Odo { get; private set; }
    public int Ltd { get; private set; }
    public string Merchant { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public decimal Total_Quote_Amount { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public string Comment { get; private set; }
    public string Uploaded_By { get; private set; } //TODO Identity Manager
    public DateTime Date_Uploaded { get; private set; }
    public IList<ClearanceLineItem> ClearanceLineItems { get; private set; }
}

public class ClearanceLineItem
{
    public string Item_Number { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public float Qty { get; private set; }
    public decimal Avg { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
}
```

I am trying to inherit from it like so:

```
public class VehicleClearance: Clearance
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int VehicleId { get; private set; }
    public string Clearance_Number { get; private set; }   
}
```

When mapping to a database via EF Core, I get the table name `VehicleClearance` and `ClearanceLineItem`.

Is it possible to configure EF Core to infer the name of the table to `VehicleCleranceLineItems`, because there will be other classes that will be inheriting from `Clearance` class (i.e `TurndownClearance`, `JobCardClearance`)

Comment: So I have to specifically create a class `VehicleClearanceLineItems`? it can't be inferred, because I will have many classes that will inherit from the `Clearance` Class

Comment: NO.  You *have*  a class ("ClearanceLineItem").  You just need to declare the *List* of "ClearanceLineItems" in your DB Context class.  Just as I assume you already declared "Clearance" in your DB Context class.

Comment: Please see if these links help: [How to configure one-to-many relationship with navigation property ... in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66418961/421195), [Nested fields in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73168521/421195).  KEY POINTS: 1) define your models (C# classes), 2) Ensure your models allow for EF navigation, 3) Declare the models in your DB context (another C# class), 4) Optionally, customer the builder method, and finally 5) Make the appropriate quer(ies)